# Append Tool is not transfering all data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, append

I am trying to append one polygon shapefile to an empty polygon feature class. The append works without any errors that I can use to troubleshoot. Unfortunately, out of 59 polygons in the shapefile, only 52 are added to the empty feature class.

I'm not sure what steps to take to troubleshoot this issue. Does anyone have any suggestions on what could be causing the problem?

Edit: Steps taken so far;
I tried appending just the 7 missing polygons. The Append tool runs fine and reports no errors..but does not add the 7 missing polygons. I tried exporting those polygons to a new shapefile and appending that shapefile, also to no luck.

I ran Check Geometry and found no geometry errors. All 7 parcels have only the default ArcMap fields (objectID, shape, Shape_length, and Shape_area) plus one ID field which is just 0 for every polygon including the ones that appended successfully.

Comment: I would examine the 7 polygons that did not transfer. Do they have an area?If not, they may have Null geometry. You can run Check Geometry to find invalid geometry.

Comment: @klewis , Unfortunately that didn't produce anything. Check geometry gave an empty table. all 7 polygons have an area.

Comment: Check the properties of the feature's spatial index in ArcCatalog. If it's missing, it may be rejecting records that it thinks are outside your limits of the append target file. I cannot recall if I got an error every time when this happened to me. You can rebuild the index easily if you have schema modification privileges on the file.

Comment: Set environment extent to union of inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some "null" value on a field in the input.
If the target require a field "not nullable" the row in the input that contain a null will be not appended.